# node postgres "client is not defined" & Cannot read property 'query' of undefined errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

Please be nice, I know I'm a noob and a half.

I am successfully connected to my database. Yay. However, when trying to sign in a user, I am getting the error `client is not defined`

As you can see in my `auth-access.js`, I attempt to define client (it is commented out for now), but then I would get the error `Cannot read property 'query' of undefined`

I know I'm missing something here, but I'm going nuts, can't figure it out! Any help is much appreciated.

Here is my code.

pg-access.js

```
const { Pool } = require("pg");

const localConfig = {
    database: process.env.PG_DATABASE,
    user: process.env.PG_USER,
    port: process.env.PG_PORT,
    password: process.env.PG_PASSWORD,
};

const herokuAddonConfig = {
    connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
};

const pool = new Pool(
    process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? herokuAddonConfig : localConfig
);

connectToDb = async () => {
    // ASYNC CONNECT TO DB

    try {
        await pool.connect();
        console.log("connected to chat_app database");
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("Not connected to DB" + err);
    }
};

module.exports = { connectToDb };
```

auth-access.js

```
//const saltRounds = 10;
const pgAccess = require("./pg-access");
require("dotenv").config();
require("../routes/auth-routes");
require("pg");
//const { Client } = require("pg");

// let client = await pgAccess.connectToDb();


loginUser = async (name, password) => {
    try {
        await client.query("BEGIN");
        const results = await client.query(
            `SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '${name}';`
        );
        const saltedPassword = results.rows[0].password;
        const passwordMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, saltedPassword);

        if (results.rows[0].is_logged_in == true) {
            return {
                isSuccessful: false,
                errorMessage: "This user is already logged in",
            };
        }

        if (!passwordMatch) {
            return {
                isSuccessful: false,
                errorMessage: "Incorrect password",
            };
        } else {
            await client.query(
                `UPDATE users SET last_active_at = NOW() WHERE username = '${name}'`
            );
            await client.query(
                `UPDATE users SET is_logged_in = true WHERE username = '${name}'`
            );
            await client.query("COMMIT");
        }
        let successfulLogin = {
            isSuccessful: true,
            errorMessage: null,
            user: results.rows[0],
        };
        return successfulLogin;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(`User not logged in ${err}`);
        return {
            isSuccessful: false,
            errorMessage: "Could not locate this username. Please register.",
        };
    }
};

logOutUser = async name => {
    try {
        await client.query("BEGIN");
        const results = await client.query(
            `SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '${name}'`
        );
        await client.query(
            `UPDATE users SET is_logged_in = false WHERE username = '${name}'`
        );
        await client.query("COMMIT");
        return results.rows[0];
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(`Could not logout user ${err}`);
        return false;
    }
};

putLogoutUser = async id => {
    try {
        await client.query("BEGIN");
        await client.query(`SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '${id}'`);
        await client.query(
            `UPDATE users SET is_logged_in = false WHERE id = '${id}'`
        );
        await client.query("COMMIT");
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(`Could not logout user ${err}`);
        return false;
    }
};

module.exports = { loginUser, logOutUser, putLogoutUser };
```

and just for kicks, here is the specific route this is attempting to interact with:

auth-routes.js

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const pgAccess = require("../database/pg-access");
const authAccess = require("../database/authAccess");
const socketService = require("../services/socket-service");
const io = socketService.getIo();

router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
    const loginName = req.body.userName;
    const password = req.body.password;
    let userMatch = await authAccess.loginUser(loginName, password);

    if (!userMatch.isSuccessful) {
        res.status(401).json({
            message: userMatch.errorMessage,
        });
    } else {
        userMatch = userMatch.user;

        res.status(201).send({ userMatch });
    }

    io.emit("user_online", JSON.stringify(userMatch));
});

router.post("/logout", async (req, res) => {
    const id = req.body.id;
    let logOutName = req.body.userName;

    const userMatch = await authAccess.logOutUser(logOutName);

    if (!userMatch) {
        res.status(401).json({
            message: "there was an issue logging out",
        });
    } else {
        res.status(201).send({ userMatch });
    }

    io.emit("user_disconnect", JSON.stringify(id));
});

router.put("/logout/:id", async (req, res) => {
    const id = req.params.id;

    await authAccess.putLogoutUser(id);

    io.emit("user_disconnect", JSON.stringify(id));
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: ```await``` does not work outside of an ```async``` function. So  you will not be able to await your connectToDb where you are trying to do it in your code.

Comment: interesting, and arguably I don't need to await a connection since it is already connected? What about the query calls? No await there needed either?

Comment: I'm assuming your query calls are promises, so you will definitely need to await them if you want to get the returned value and not a pending promise. You'll probably need to rethink how you handle the connection to the database. I usually use a promise in my server entry file and connect to the database, then start the server.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I believe that I am using promises to connect to the DB in my ```pg-access.js``` file. Unless I am missing something. It seems to me that I am not importing the ```pg-access``` file into my ```auth-acess.js```. Isn't that what I should be focusing on? I am a bit lost on that.